# Django view showing error in virtual environment

Tags: python, django

I am using virtual Environment to develop the project. Using python3 and Django 1.9.7
I am splitting views into multiple files. Below is the tree structure.

```
|-- urls.pyc
`-- Views
    |-- DashboardView.py
    |-- DashboardView.pyc
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- __init__.pyc
    |-- __pycache__
    |   |-- DashboardView.cpython-34.pyc
    |   |-- __init__.cpython-34.pyc
    |   `-- VehicleView.cpython-34.pyc
    |-- VehicleView.py
    `-- VehicleView.pyc
```

Inside `__init__.py` file -

```
from VehicleView import *
from DashboardView import *
```

When I am activating virtual environment and running code it throws me below error -

```
File "/home/rana/DjangoProject/FirstChoice/MyFirstCar/MyFirstCarBackEnd/Views/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from VehicleView import *
ImportError: No module named 'VehicleView'
```

If I do not activate the virtual environment and run the code, it runs without any error. Default django version 1.8.4 and python 2.7.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `__init__.py` try to use local imports instead, this may be a problem if you are using `python3` in your virtual environment.

```
from .VehicleView import *
from .DashboardView import *
```

Besides file and module names in python should follow snake case convention, only classes should use CamelCase.

```
from .vehicle_view import *
form .dashboard_view import *
```

Comment: what is a local import? what are other type of imports?

Comment: @User42 "local import" means "importing from files in the same directory". "Importing" is the action of including code from other files in the current file so you can use it without needing to copy/paste tons of stuff. [Here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Beginner%27s_Python_Tutorial/Importing_Modules) is an example of how to write importable modules, and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) is the documentation for the import system.